# change of datepicker format in android

Tags: android, datepicker, format

i have used a datepicker but i wanted to use dd/mm/yy format can i do this ??
please provide sample code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check here ,
[DatePicker Widget Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499433/android-datepicker-widget-format)