# android: datepicker with italian date

Tags: android, datepicker

I've got a "normal" `DatePicker` that is made like this:

```
// funzioni del datepicker
protected DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
    }
};
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    return new DatePickerDialog(this.getParent(),mDateSetListener,mYear, mMonth, mDay);
}
```

and I call `showDialog(0);` to expose this.

It works, but the date is in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format. I need to change it in the `dd-mm-yyyy` format.
Also, can i add the hour and minutes to this?

Comment: Search please. [Change date format link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208769/android-how-to-change-the-datepicker-view-date-format-from-mm-dd-yyyy-to-dd-mm

Comment: Do you want to change its view date format ?

Comment: yes. now i see Tuesday, August 28, 2012 and then the three "chooser" putted in this way: mm-dd-yyyy

i want to see Martedì, 28 agosto, 2012 and then the three "chooser" putted in this way: dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: uao, wait: it's system-language dependant!
so i'm ok.

Comment: i need only to add hour and second

Answer (score 1):

// Converting Date format from (YYYY_MM-DD) to (DD-MM-YYYY)

```
private String convertDate(String cdate)
{
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date convertedDate;    
convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(cdate);
cdate = postFormater.format(convertedDate);
return cdate;
}
```