# DatePicker widget: Always display date in format YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: android, datepicker

I have been struggling with this for a while.

**Is there a method to ALWAYS display the date format in YYYY/MM/DD in a DatePicker widget regardless of user specific locales?**

I have been searching the web for the whole day but I can only find how to get the date/time and convert it to other formats but not how to actually get the cursed widget to display a different time format.

The only related answer that I can find on stackoverflow is **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208769/android-how-to-change-the-datepicker-view-date-format-from-mm-dd-yyyy-to-dd-mm)**. Surely there has to be an easier way than to brute force the API.

**To clarify my context and usage:** I'm using my DatePicker in a Fragment(NOT DialogFragment extending a DatePickerDialog).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
    int dayOfMonth) {

int month = monthOfYear + 1;
String formattedMonth = "" + month;
String formattedDayOfMonth = "" + dayOfMonth;

if(month < 10){

    formattedMonth = "0" + month;
}
if(dayOfMonth < 10){

    formattedDayOfMonth = "0" + dayOfMonth;
}
searchText.setText(formattedDayOfMonth + "/" + formattedMonth + "/" + year);
```

}

Comment: hmmm... this is for a DatePickerDialog. I have updated my question to clarify my context.

Comment: Even so, from what I see in your code snippet, your answer doesn't do the trick.