# Changing the layout of DatePicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Is there any way to reformat the datePicker so that instead of getting "mm/dd/yyyy" you can get "dd/mm/yyyy" or even "dd/mm/yy"

This is my current code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import java.util.Calendar;


/**
 * Created by MOS182 on 7/21/13.
 */
public class AddReminder extends Activity {

    TextView Title, Amount, PaymentDate, ReminderDate, ReminderTime;
    EditText eTitle, eAmount, ePaymentDate, eReminderDate, eReminderTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminders_dialog);
        initializeVariables();

        ePaymentDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //To show current date in the datepicker
                Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
                mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(AddReminder.this, new OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                        selectedmonth = selectedmonth + 1;
                        ePaymentDate.setText("" + selectedday + "/" + selectedmonth + "/" + selectedyear);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");
                mDatePicker.show();
            }
        });


    }





    private void initializeVariables()
    {
        Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        Amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);
        PaymentDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPaymentDate);
        ReminderDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvReminderDate);
        ReminderTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvReminderTime);
        eTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
        eAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmount);
        ePaymentDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPaymentDate);
        eReminderDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etReminderDate);
        eReminderTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etReminderTime);
    }


}
```

This is what is currently displayed when I run my code and select the ePaymentDate field.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picker take the date format chosen by the user, which means you don't really have to format it, as probably the **user** enjoys the most to **see the format** he's **used to.**

I just tested a code and on my phone, where I have the date in (dd/mm/yyyy) format, so the picker shows the same format; in emulator, I've put the date in mm/dd/yyyy format, so the picker displays the same.

So there is ***no method to set the display format***.

But if you still really want to display a specific format, then refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208769/android-how-to-change-the-datepicker-view-date-format-from-mm-dd-yyyy-to-dd-mm), there is an elaborate way to show the date in the desired format, but with changes in the original code.

Comment: I'm used to seeing dd/mm/yyyy however when I run the emulator it comes up mm/dd/yyyy, will it run as dd/mm/yyyy when I run it on my phone?

Comment: If on your phone it is dd/mm/yyyy, yes, it will come as dd/mm/yyyy. Try it. It should work.