# DatePickerDialog with custom values

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-datepicker

I'm using the [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker) and it works like a charm. Now I would like to set my own values from 3 string arrays (array.xml) into the datepicker. The reason is that I'm changing the locale inside the app, instead of the entire phone.

Is this possible? Or should I make a custom picker instead of the DatePicker? I searched for it but can't find anything that suits my request.

Cheers!

Edit:

Standard DatePicker have: Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May...Dec. But when I change the locale it should change to: (ES) Ene, Feb, Mar, Abr, May...Dic

Comment: Would i be possible to change the language of what i get from calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understand, but in the `OnCreateDialog()` method, just return

```
  return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
```

With `year`, `month` & `day` the date you want

EDIT : Some bad news : [This link shows that there is a method to reorder and change Locale of a DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208769/android-how-to-change-the-datepicker-view-date-format-from-mm-dd-yyyy-to-dd-mm)

but

`reorderPickers(String[] months)` is private. I think you should have a look at `android.widget.DatePicker` to understand it and to write your personnal class :)

This method is used to change the datePicker to match with the local phone setting

Comment: Bad question maybe. But in the standard datepicker there is Jan, Feb....May, Oct etc. But for ex swedish that would be Maj, Okt and in spanish/french something else. The dateformat is no problem. The strings in the standard datepicker doesn't change on locale inside the app.

Comment: Looks crazy but I will give it a try. :) Thx.