# How to create an android custom DatePicker with day of week and month?

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I have to extend DatePicker to custom it and show the picker in this format:
Monday, 12 November. How can I do? Which method I have to implement?

Comment: check this : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208769/android-how-to-change-the-datepicker-view-date-format-from-mm-dd-yyyy-to-dd-mm

Comment: check out this https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers
may be it would help you