# change date format in datepicker dialog android

Tags: android, datepicker, date-format

I have edit text field and I have a method that handles onclick event on edit field and show up a date picker dialog. However I want to change date format in the dialog . It shows Aug 31 2014, I like to show 31 08 2014. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered elsewhere on the site, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499433/datepicker-widget-format) for example. Basically the datepicker dialog shows up in the preferred format of the end user, so if they have their phone or emulator set to mm/dd/yyyy it will show up like that, if you want it to come up dd/mm/yyyy while you are testing it make sure your emulator is set up with that as the preferred date format.

Answer (score 0):

In `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` you will get `onDateSet` method where you can get

```
int year = selectedYear;
int month = selectedMonth;
int day = selectedDay;

dateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    dateCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    dateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
String monthname =  new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(dateCalendar.getTime());
```

in SimpleDateFormat you can change date format as you want

Comment: Your code format date in the text field in which the date will be shown I like to change date format in the datepicker dialog window

Comment: Hello Vikifor ,With the ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499433/datepicker-widget-format ,  there is no method to set display format