# How to change gap size between buttons in Android DatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker

Ideally, I'd like to be able to make the datepicker a little smaller. However, that seems not an option based on my internet search. But it might okay, if I could squeeze the buttons a little closer. So, how to change the gap size between button in the DatePicker?

Comment: You can't customize the default DatePicker. See [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325587/customize-datepicker-android/4325762#4325762

Comment: If this is really truth, i'd be very disappointed.

Comment: @miliu, I agree... let's all demand our money back!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325587/customize-datepicker-android) you're pretty much stuck with what you got... but if I'm wrong, I'd love to know how to do it! :)